# Is it possible to create a logger that prefixes any serilog message?

Tags: serilog

Is it possible to create a logger that automatically prefixes every message?

I usually prefix every message with the account because this makes it easier to read them, something like this:

```
user1 - did something
user2 - did another thing
```

I'd like to create a logger that automatically adds this prefix to any message logger *by that specific logger*. Currently I do something like:

```
var log = Log.ForContext("username", user1);
log.Information("{username} - did something");
```

I'd like to do this:

```
var log = Log.ForContext("username", user1);
log.Information("did something");
```

and achieve the same result without having to add the prefix to each message.

Is there any built-in way to achieve this? Or am I looking this the wrong way?

Comment: Pretty sure `log.Information("{username} - did something")` will choke as you're expected to supply an arg per parameter. Install https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer and it'll even complain at you!

Comment: That log works find as long as I don't add any parameters. If I need to add any parameters, it replaces the `{username}` with the first parameter. Maybe as you said, with properties that would work.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to format the message, you can do exactly what you ask by referring to the field in the message template like so:

```
{UserName}{Message}{NewLine}
```

But the typical way this is achieved is by using the `{Properties}` meta-property, which renders all values not used in the actual message that happen to have been captured into / added by enrichers / added by you via `ForContext` in the `Properties` of the `LogEvent`

```
{Message} {Properties}{NewLine}
```

See https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output

Comment: The problem with message formatting is that 1) I'm logging to elastic search, so I don't have any format to log, 2) even with formatting, I'd need to filter out these messages and apply different formats depending on a lot of things, as they don't come from a single place.

Comment: sounds like this is complex and/or specific enough to be best managed as a github issue or a gitter question